# Titan graph (embedded Cassandra - Elasticsearch), Import CSV files using existing external indexed property keys

Tags: properties, import, key, gremlin, titan

I need to figure out how to import CSV files using pre-defined indexed property keys, I tried this:

With a empty Titan graph this code works perfectly

**new File("/home/User/titan-server-0.4.2/propnodes.csv").eachLine{ line ->
(BaseRecId,StreetNumber,StreetName,StreetSuffix,City,County,State,Zip) = line.split(",");**

**prop = g.addVertex("BaseRecId::"+BaseRecId);**

**ElementHelper.setProperties(prop, ["BaseRecId" : BaseRecId,"StreetNumber": StreetNumber,"StreetName" : StreetName,"StreetSuffix" : StreetSuffix,"City" : City,"County": County,"State" : State,"Zip" : Zip])}**

Now, due Titan indexes need to be setup before to populate any data, first step I do this:

**g.makeKey('BaseRecId').dataType(Integer.class).indexed('search', Vertex.class).make();
g.makeKey('StreetName').dataType(String.class).indexed('search', Vertex.class).make();**

and then when I try to import the data with the above code, and I got this error

**An error occurred while processing the script for language [groovy]. All transactions across all graphs in the session have been concluded with failure: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "BaseRecId"**

How can I import CSV files using existing external indexed property Keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined `BaseRecId` as an integer but you are trying to push it in as a string.  Your code should look something like this:

```
ElementHelper.setProperties(prop, ["BaseRecId" : Integer.parseInt(BaseRecId),"StreetNumber": StreetNumber,"StreetName" : StreetName,"StreetSuffix" : StreetSuffix,"City" : City,"County": County,"State" : State,"Zip" : Zip])}
```

Also `g.addVertex` will not respect that ID you are passing it.  Titan does not allow for user supplied ids.  Finally, you might consider using [groovy-csv](http://xlson.com/groovycsv/) for working with CSV files in the Gremlin REPL.

Comment: Thank you Stephen for the helpful approach, even when the problem still, I've changed **prop = g.addVertex("BaseRecId::"+BaseRecId)** to **prop = g.addVertex()** and I made a String type key BaseRecId, and it worked. I wonder why it doesn't work with integer, I've tried **"BaseRecId" : Integer.parseInt(BaseRecId)** and **'BaseRecId' : BaseRecId.toInteger()** with the same error above.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, however if you wanted to do numerical range queries, a String won't help you do that i don't think.  Not sure why Integer doesn't work for.  The "graph of the gods" example shows that it is possible: https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/master/titan-core/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/titan/example/GraphOfTheGodsFactory.java#L52

Comment: Yeah, I've seem that, anyways, I'm moving forward. Thanks for your help!